# allowable arrangements of ${1,2,2,3,3,3...}$

Tags: combinations

You are given the multiset $\{1,2,2,3,3,3,\ldots\}$ with each type$(n)$ having $n$ elements.If you pick the first $k$ types, how many allowable arrangements are there using $k$ elements?  For $k=5$ you could have $\{1,2,3,3,3\}$ or $\{2,3,4,4,4\}$ but not $\{1,1,2,3,5\}$ or $\{2,2,2,4,5\}$. Is there an easy way to answer this question?  One way is to take $k^k$ and then subtract all unallowable arrangements, but is this any easier?

Comment: I thought the convention for subsets was to enclose them in {   }.

Comment: The braces were there, there were just no backslashes in front of them so they were taken as MathJax syntax.

Comment: The question has been misunderstood: it does not ask for the allowable combinations with repetitions but for the number of ordered arrangements of them. Hence with allowable 2,2,3,3,3 one gets 5!/2!*3!=10 of them, as in 2,3,3,3,2 and 3,2,2,3,3. I hoped that mentioning k^k then removing the unallowable arrangements would give the meaning of the question. For k=1 to 5 I got for solution 1,3,19,176,2111. For k=3 you get 1,2,2 with 3 arrangements; 1,2,3 with 6; 1,3,3 with 3; 2,3,3 with 3, 2,3,3 with 3; 3,3,3 with 1 giving 3+6+3+3+3+1=19. – J. M. Bergot 1 min ago   edit

Comment: See A000707, which answers the question of how many submultisets are derived from 1,2,2,3,3,3... My question is to find the total number of arrangements (ordered multisets) ; I will demonstrate using k=3, having 6  multisets ('combinations with repetition' in the original question). Let '@m" mean 'has m ordered multisets'.  The 6 multisets are 1,2,2 @3; 1,2,3 @6; 1,3,3 @3; 2,2,3 @3; 2,3,3 @3; 3,3,3 @1.  Adding 3+6+3+3+3+1=19.  For k=1 to 4 you get  1,3,19,175 ordered multisets.  To insure the understanding of ordered multiset (arrangement) 1,2,2 has three: 1,2,2 and 2,1,2 and 2,2,1.

Comment: One could extend this by considering progressive submultisets by taking the first m<=k and finding the sum of all arrangements.  To demonstrate with k=3: m=1 means pick any one from 1,2,3 to give 1 @1; 2 @1; 3 @1 for a total of 3.  For m=2 pick 1,2 @2; 2,2 @1; 1,3 @2; 3,3 @1; 2,2 @1; 2,3 @2; 3,3 @1 for a total of  10.  Finally, take all 3, as in  above comment of 19; now add 3+10+19=32.  From k=1 to 4 the sequence is 1,2,32,284.

Comment: Consider the question of the sum of the terms for the submultisets.  For k=1 to 4 the sequence begins 1,7,42,234 or the sum of the terms of all ordered submultisets, which gives 1,10,126,1904.

Comment: One could alter the original multiset 1,2,2,3,3,3...by considering triangular numbers, to give 1,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6...or squares, to give 1,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.  Ask the same questions as for the original.

Comment: If you can clarify the question do so by editing it, then we can consider reopening it, just posting new comments won't help.

Comment: I'll do  it tomorrow, Aug 10.

Answer (score 1):

Picking the first $k$ types, you get a subset of your multiset with length $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$.  For example, for $k=4$:
$$
|\left\{1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4 \right\}| = \frac{4(5)}{2} = 10
$$
This is because the cardinality of the chosen subset with respect to $k$ is the $k$th triangular number, as you sum the numbers 1 through $k$.

You must choose $k$ elements of the subset, unless I'm misunderstanding something, and order does not matter, so the formula for the number of allowable arrangements using k elements is:
$$
\binom {\dfrac{k(k+1)}{2}} {k}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have by inspection that the generating function for these is

$$(1+x)(1+x+x^2)\times\cdots\times(1+x+\cdots+x^k)$$

and the desired value is thus given by

$$[x^k] \prod_{q=1}^k \frac{1-x^{q+1}}{1-x}.$$

This produces the sequence

$$1, 2, 6, 20, 71, 259, 961, 3606, 13640, 51909, \ldots$$

which  is [OEIS A000707](https://oeis.org/A000707)  where we  see that
apparently no better closed form exists.